# Python prime numbers

Tags: python, numbers

Hi I'm new in programming and in python and I have an assignment that I can't complete. I have to write a Python program to compute and print the first 200 prime numbers. The output must be formatted with a title and the prime numbers must be printed in 5 properly aligned columns. I have used this code so far:

```
numprimes = raw_input('Prime Numbers  ')    
count = 0    
potentialprime = 2

def primetest(potentialprime):
    divisor = 2
    while divisor <= potentialprime:
        if potentialprime == 2:
            return True
        elif potentialprime % divisor == 0:
            return False
            break
        while potentialprime % divisor != 0:
            if potentialprime - divisor > 1:
                divisor += 1
            else:
                return True

while count < int(numprimes):
    if primetest(potentialprime) == True:
        print potentialprime
        count += 1
        potentialprime += 1
    else:
        potentialprime += 1
```

But I get the result in a single column. How can I get it in 5 rows?

Comment: Please paste your actual code. Then highlight it all and click the `{}` button. Stuff got garbled in posting.

Answer (score 1):

```
col=0                  #add this line
while count < int(numprimes):
    if primetest(potentialprime) == True:
        print "%5d"%potentialprime, #and this line
        col += 1        #and this block
        if col==5:      #
            print "\n"  #
            col=0       #
        count += 1
        potentialprime += 1
    else:
        potentialprime += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a variable for the number of the current column `currentCol` initialized to 0 and change the line `print potentialprime` to the following 5 lines:

```
print str(potentialprime).ljust(5),
currentCol += 1
if currentCol==5:
    print ""
    currentCol=0
```

Take notice of the call to [`ljust`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.ljust) and the `,` at the end of the `print` line that prevents a newline at the end of printed number. After the 5 columns printed (`if currentCol==5`) you print a newline and reset `currentCol` to 0.

See http://ideone.com/WsLnDK for the whole modified program with your intended output.

Answer (score 0):

```py
while count < int(numprimes):
    if primetest(potentialprime) == True:
        print "%5d" % potentialprime, #and this line
        col += 1        #and this block

        if col == 5:      #
            print "\n"    #
            col = 0       #

        count += 1
        potentialprime += 1
    else:
        potentialprime += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# The below code will print 1 prime number or a range of prime numbers if passed 
# in the range.

def primeNumber(num):
for i in range(2,num):
    if num%i==0:
        return f"{num} - not a prime number"
        break
else:
    return f"{num} - is a prime number"

mylist = [i for i in range(1,100)]
for i in mylist:
    print(primeNumber(i))
```